# Playlist video API missed certain posts when ran on particular day

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I use Youtube APIs to keep track of the brand assets of a certain channel.
Playlist API: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems
There is a weekly refresh on the platform. In one of the refresh, playlist API missed a certain post in the corresponding week. Post published date was well within the range.
Any justifiable reason for this issue? Just want to get the root cause and probability for this issue to occur, so that I can build some safeguard on my platforms if required.

Comment: I guess you should elaborate more. Are you referring to new videos in the Uploads playlist?

Comment: [edit] your question and provide more information. which information/post are missing?, which is the "corresponding week"?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge the result set obtained from PlaylistItems endpoint should be exact -- no fuzziness implied like in the case of Search endpoint. Therefore I am inclined to believe -- you did not provided actual data along with your question -- that there is something else that caused your issue.

Often users of the API overlook the fact that any video could first be uploaded as *private* and only later made public.

> [**publishedAt**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.publishedAt) (datetime)
>
> The date and time that the video was published. *Note that this time might be different than the time that the video was uploaded.* For example, if a video is uploaded as a private video and then made public at a later time, this property will specify the time that the video was made public.